#  android image copy problem

Tags: android, image, copy

i use this for save image From a gallery and copy to (/data/data/fshizzle_eval.com/files/image.jpg), work only if the image (/data/data/fshizzle_eval.com/files/image.jpg) already exists:

```
// Save                 
                try {
                    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/data/data/fshizzle_eval.com/files/image.jpg"));


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

if the image does not exist i this msg in my logcat and the image chosen from the gallery is not copied

```
07-06 21:44:48.839: WARN/System.err(3854): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/fshizzle_eval.com/files/image.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

How fix this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a file in a folder that probably doesn't exist. Check if the folder exists first. If not, create it, and then try writing to the file.

```
File file = new File("/data/data/fshizzle_eval.com/files");
if(!file.exists){
   file.mkdirs();
}
```